# Magento Search Not Finding Newly Created Products

Tags: php, html, magento, sphinx, magento-1.8

Our server was recently moved and rebuilt (and that's when the issue began).

The search does find products, but only those that have been created (or been enabled) before the transfer.  When I search in a category in the catalog, I can find the newly created/uploaded product.  It just cannot seem to be accessed by Search.

We are using Magento 1.8.1 and the SPHINX extension (supported by mirasvit).

Comment: If you go to System->Index Management, are there any indexes that are not in status "ready?"

Comment: @tsHunter 
I have re-indexed it several times after trying to alter the search parameters, along with deleting the cache & session logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After backing up our server from a previous date, I was able to locate and eliminate the issue.  It was regarding the cache that was created from the product, and it was being misplaced.  Took hours of searching, but everything is working beautifully now. =)

Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your product's Visibility is disabled. Check your Visibility  of your product. `Admin-> catalog -> Select that Product -> General -> Visibility` 
set value to `Catalog, search`.

Comment: I have already checked visibility properties, along with search properties.  But, it still does not make a difference. It does not want to be searchable.  It is seriously becoming a pain.  And the website is selected, along with it being in a category (I know sometimes that can make a difference).

Comment: Did you configured multi store ? if yes check that product belongs to which store (website). If it is not help then delete your database and import again or just delete that product create again.

Comment: I hate to say it, but our store has over 5,000 products.  We do have back-ups, but that is not going to fix the issue (I have tried).  Deleting and recreating the product made no difference.  Like I have stated before, you can see the product(s) in the store, they just do not show up in the search results - the ones that were created or enabled after the server transfer.

Thank you for your assistance.  I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If visibility is set to catalog/search, please check the product is enabled or disabled. Wile importing or exporting the products, it seems to change the status of the products.

Comment: I make a mental note to always check for product status; to change it from disabled to enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you can try by checking product visibility to see whether it has value Catalog, Search or not.